# Appium: How to use ios predicate strategy for XCUIElement

Tags: java, ios, xpath, appium, xctest

I'm writing mobile autotest using appium 1.6.0-beta1, Xcode 8, iPhone iOS 10 simulator and java.

I want to find elements not using xpath.
In appium 1.5.3 it was possible to use Ios Automation (in appium java-client  there was MobileBy.ByIosUIAutomation), but now UI Automation is replaced by XCUITest.

I've found, that ios predicate can be used to find XCUI elements (MobileBy.ByIosNsPredicate in appium java-client 5.0.0).

My question is how to find elements using ios predicate?

Here i've found rules for UIAutomation: http://appium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/en/writing-running-appium/ios_predicate/#appium-predicate-helpers.
For example, here is ios predicate equivalent for xpath:

**ios predicate**: *tableViews()[1].cells().firstWithPredicate("label == 'Olivia' ")*

**xpath**: */UIATableView[2]/UIATableCell[@label = 'Olivia'][1]*

What ios predicate should I use for such xpath:
*//XCUIElementTypeCell/XCUIElementTypeStaticText[3]* ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

first of all in xcode ui test, you can use NSPredicate like below way :

```
NSPredicate(format: "label CONTAINS 'your label string'")
```

or

```
NSPredicate(format: "label BEGINSWITH 'your label string'")
```

or

```
NSPredicate(format: "label ENDSWITH 'your label string'")
```

or

```
NSPredicate(format: "label == 'your label string'")
```

so, in your case, your solution is

```
app.cells.matchingPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "label CONTAINS 'Olivia'"))
```

this returns xcelementquery that means you will get one or more elements.
From there, you can pick your desired element like:

```
let elem = app.cells.matchingPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "label CONTAINS 'Olivia'")).elementBoundByIndex(0) //it may be 0 or 1 or 2
//you can know this using p print in debug mode.
```

now use this elem to tap or get anything from this elem.

```
elem.tap()
```

hope this helps and let me know.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot. It really works!! I still don't know how to write more complicated locators, for example, with indixes. Now i'm trying to find some ns predicates rules. Maybe you know, where I can find?

Comment: This is how element is initialized in java: new MobileBy.ByIosNsPredicate("label CONTAINS 'Olivia'")